# "The specified OData query has invalid real literal"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, odata, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Android and Azure Mobile Apps backend. I recently noticed that on certain devices a function causes an unhandled exception.

This is the function that causes the error. I am querying map markers from a local database based on the device's location, which is given as a parameter.

```
public static async Task<List<Marker>> GetMarkersAroundPosition(LatLng position)
{
    if (position == null)
        throw new NullPointerException(Resources.System.GetString(Resource.String.dbErrorPositionNullOrEmpty));

    //Calculate the latitude at the current longitude
    double lonInKm = CalcLat(position.Longitude);
    //Fetch the markers from DB
    return await Client.GetSyncTable<Marker>().Where(Marker => Marker.Lat < position.Latitude + Constants.LatInKm
    && Marker.Lat > position.Latitude - Constants.LatInKm
    && Marker.Lon < position.Longitude + lonInKm 
    && Marker.Lon > position.Longitude - lonInKm).ToListAsync();
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceODataException: The specified odata query has invalid real literal '60.9852519308129'.
```

I've uploaded the full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/jvfrDXFc).

This happens only on certain devices. Here's the list of physical devices I've tested the app on:

```
Works:
    Lenovo Tab 4 8 LTE (TB-8504X), 7.1.1
    Alcatel Idol 4 (TLC 6055K) 6.0.1
    Motorola Moto G5S Plus (XT1805), 7.1.1
    Motorola Moto G5 (XT1676), 7.0
    Samsung Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7 (SM-T550), 7.1.1
    Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 (GT-P5220), 7.1.2 (LineageOS 14.1)
    Sony Xperia XZ1 (G8441), 8.0.0

Doesn't:
    Motorola Moto X Play (XT1652), 7.1.1
    Nokia 6 TA1021, 8.1.0
    Samsung Galaxy Note8 (SM-N950F), 8.0.0
    Motorola Moto G5 Plus (XT1685), 7.0
    OnePlus 3T (A3003) 8.0.0
```

I am really lost on this one because there doesn't seem to be a clear reason why the app runs just fine on some devices and crashes on others.

**EDIT:**

It seems to be a locale problem. I created a small test app for testing the Double.TryParse function as suggested on the [Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/338424/#Comment_338424) forums, and also tested the app in development in different languages. All test resulted in that the app would crash if the device language was set to Finnish, and worked perfectly normal when the language was set to English.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceODataException: The specified odata query has invalid real literal '60.9852519308129'.

Based on your stack trace, I found the code line where the exception threw. You could check the `ParseRealLiteral` method under [ODataExpressionParser.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Table/Query/OData/ODataExpressionParser.cs) as follows:

```html
        private QueryNode ParseRealLiteral()
        {
            this.ValidateToken(QueryTokenKind.RealLiteral, () => "Expected real literal.");
            string text = this.lexer.Token.Text;
            char last = Char.ToUpper(text[text.Length - 1]);
            if (last == 'F' || last == 'M' || last == 'D')
            {
                // so terminating F/f, M/m, D/d have no effect.
                text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
            }
            object value = null;
            switch (last)
            {
                case 'M':
                    decimal mVal;
                    if (Decimal.TryParse(text, out mVal))
                    {
                        value = mVal;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    float fVal;
                    if (Single.TryParse(text, out fVal))
                    {
                        value = fVal;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                default:
                    double dVal;
                    if (Double.TryParse(text, out dVal))
                    {
                        value = dVal;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if (value == null)
            {
                this.ParseError("The specified odata query has invalid real literal '{0}'.".FormatInvariant(text), this.lexer.Token.Position);
            }

            this.lexer.NextToken();
            return new ConstantNode(value);
        }
```

Per my understanding, your input `60.9852519308129(m|f|d)` should work as expected based on your specific detailed error message.

> 07-04 11:01:05.653 I/MonoDroid(29937):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.**MobileServiceTableQuery**`1+
>   **ToListAsync** d__33[T].MoveNext () :0 An unhandled exception occurred.

It seems the `where` clause throws the exception. I assume that it causes by the specific stored data or query statement, please try to use the same local SQLite db to check this issue for each devices. Moreover, you could try to [Debugging the Offline Cache](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#debugging-the-offline-cache) to find whether it could help you to diagnose this issue.